# windows 7 64 bit is installing 32 bit of meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor, installation

windows7 64 bit is installing 32 bit of meteor. and means i can't do the basic tutorial past stage 3. 
here is cmd response:

```
C:\Users\Owner\simple-todos>meteor mongo
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.7
connecting to: 127.0.0.1:3001/meteor
Server has startup warnings:
2015-10-19T10:57:33.910+1100 [initandlisten]
2015-10-19T10:57:33.910+1100 [initandlisten] ** NOTE: This is a 32 bit MongoDB binary.
2015-10-19T10:57:33.910+1100 [initandlisten] **       32 bit builds are limited to less than 2GB of data (or less with -
-journal).
2015-10-19T10:57:33.910+1100 [initandlisten] **       Note that journaling defaults to off for 32 bit and is currently o
ff.
2015-10-19T10:57:33.910+1100 [initandlisten] **       See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/32bit
2015-10-19T10:57:33.910+1100 [initandlisten]
meteor:PRIMARY>
```

I've tried looking throught all the communities installing as admin making more `c:` space

Answer (score 1):

Sam,I was having the same question a few hours ago when trying to retrieve data from mongoDB into my meteor app. From my understanding mongoDB does not installed 64 bit, instead it installs 32 bit which has a limited space (2gb). I guess for now you gonna have to leave with that until mongoDB fixes this issue.There should not be any problem when following the tutorial as the meteor app connects to the server even if your computer is not 32 bit. Those messages you are getting are not errors, they are warnings instead, meaning the connections is working fine.

IF you are still having issues on following the tutorial please let me know.

note: for future issues you might have regarding meteor, please include the meteor tag as they suggest on the meteor official website, that way they will get back to you faster.

Comment: This is not an answer, please tell future readers what to do in this situation.